# 95 gmc vandura 2500 part name?

Tags: part-identification, gmc, campervan

I'm working on my 1995 gmc Vandura 2500, with 5.7L v8, TBI engine.

I am trying to figure out the name of a part that appears to be missing a tube/hose so I can find a diagram to figure out what it is missing or what it should be connected to.

It is located on the opposite side of my MAP sensor.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The part you have circled is the [EGR Valve Solenoid](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/gmc,1995,g2500,5.7l+v8,1152166,exhaust+&+emission,egr+valve+control+solenoid+/+motor,4380). It activates the EGR valve to recirculate the exhaust gasses (go figure). In your picture, you can see where the tube pointing to the bottom of the image is attached to the EGR valve itself.

[image]

**Note**: Use of link to EGR part on RockAuto is for reference of part number only. Not implying you should buy this part or even utilize RA as a source.